# How to establish simple http server on mininet

Tags: wget, mininet

I have created a simple http server on mininet simple topology host h1 using the following command

```
h1 python3 -m SimpleHTTPSErver 80 &
```

and then tried to connect h2 to h1 by using

```
h2 wget -O - h1
```

but the connection is refused

Answer (score 2):

Python3 does not have the SimpleHTTPServer module anymore. It has been deprecated and replaced by http.server. I assume you have not looked at the output of these commands.

I have successfully ran the example

```
python3 -m http.server 80
```

on h1. And was then able to connect h2 to it using h1's IP address as follows:

```
wget -O - 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: You may need "-m" in the python3 command.